# ASP.NET MVC 5: How to use a string key to access a resource message

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have an array of string keys. I want to run a loop and print the messages associated with these keys. I need to know how I can access the message using a string as a key from the `<script>` tag.

I know that I can access an individual message like:

```
"@GlobalResources.Messages.VISA"
```

but I wanna be able to do something like:

```
"@GlobalResources.Messages."+"VISA"
```

**My code:**

```
string KEYS = {"VISA", "MASTERCARD", "MEASTRO"};
foreach(string key in KEYS)
{
     //print Message
     //GlobalResources.Messages.KEY
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
GlobalResources.ResourceManager.GetObject("string KEY")
```